# Android getPackageCodePath() in API 3

Tags: android, api

I've had API 8 as my minSdkVersion on a soon-to-be-released app. Out of curiosity, I set minSdkVersion to 3 and found the only unsupported call to be context.getPackageCodePath for my recently added security calls. Do you know how to call this with an equivalent supported by earlier API versions?

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(context.getPackageCodePath());
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("classes.dex");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ApplicatoinInfo.sourceDir, it's available since API1.

```
  ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
  ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
```